# Runtime error for a basic javafx11 application using jdk11 and Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, classnotfoundexception, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Eclipse 2019-03 working with jdk11. Following the [javafx and Eclipse tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) I've added jdk11 to my module path for my project. I've created a javafx11 user library with all of the javafx jars, and added it to my module path. [Reference to my post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1436406/unable-to-get-jdk11-to-work-on-eclipse-for-developing-javafx-applications-ubun/1436525?noredirect=1#comment2167871_1436525)

I've created this very simple JavaFX program in Eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

There are no errors and it compiles, however I get this runtime error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javac
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javac
```

> How do I fix this so that I can run this basic program?

Edits:

`java -version`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The VM arguments, as per the tutorial, I've added to my project's run configuration in Eclipse:

`--module-path /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Code that worked:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```java
package hellowFx2;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    public void initialize() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
    }
}
```

hellowFx.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="hellofx.Controller">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Project structure:

hellowFx2

```
bin

src

    hellowFx2(package) 

        Main.java

        Controller.java

        hellowfx.fxml
```

Comment: Have you followed this guide: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse ?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes. I forgot to mention that I've added the VM arguments, prior to posting this question, to my run configuration as well.

Comment: Edit your question and post "how" you added those arguments, somehow the order is not right and Eclipse tries to take `javac` as your main class

Comment: So you have installed `openjfx`, and under that path you have posted you can find `javafx-base.jar` and other JavaFX modules and their native libraries? When you added your javafx11 library, it looks like [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/eclipse/ide/eclipse02.png)? Still nothing explains your error.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes. To confirm the behavior I created two more hellowFx projects. hellowFx2 behaved slightly differently as it was complaining about the fxml libraries. hellowFx3 I got rid of the hellowfx.fxml and Controller.java files and made the javafx code even simpler(still keeping the module paths and vm arguments the same) and the application worked. I'll put the code that worked in the post.

Comment: Good that you get one project running, that means your setup is correct. But the FXML project shouldn't fail, at least not with the error you have posted. Can you add the FXML file and the project structure to your post?

Comment: @JoséPereda Looking at the files again, I noticed Eclipse had a quick fix for the fxml errors, and that was "requiring javafx.fxml in module-paths". After applying the fix, the helloFx2 worked. Looking back at hellowFx (the first one), still has the issue with not finding the main class. All three projects had javafx.fxml in the user library. It seems the first hellowFx got trashed somehow. I'll still edit in the project structure and files.

Comment: Just make sure you use a consistent package name in all your files (including the `fx:controller` reference).

Answer (score 1):

I'll detail my install and setup process in case anyone else has troubles:

#### Setup for javafx11, jdk11, and Eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04

Install openjdk11 and javafx11 SDK

> `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk openjfx`

Be sure to select the SDK version of javafx!

> [javafx](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

#### Check java Version Reads Out the Correct jdk Version

> `java -version`

The output should look like this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

#### Install the Newest Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)

> [Download link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

#### When creating a project:

1. Create a new java project

   - Be sure the jdk used for the project is jdk11
   - ***Don't create module.info***
2. Right click your project folder and click "Properties". Go to the "Libraries" Tab and left click "Module Path". On the right, select "Add Library" and choose "User Library"

   - name it javafx
   - include all of the .jar files in /path/to/javafx/lib

     - Don't include anyother file type!
3. Add the newely created libary to the projects module path
4. In run configuration, found in the run taskbar, select the "Arguments" tab and add this to VM arguments:

   - `--module-path /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`
   - Be sure the path to your javafx is correct!